# Why did my build fail with "" when using python:3.7-slim?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, python-3.7, dockerhub

I use [`python:3.7-slim`](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) to automatically test my code. This month, I once had a unittest fail because suddenly `libffi-dev` was missing. The change I made was not related to this at all. Today, `libssl-dev` was missing. This was not an issue before.

Did `python:3.7-slim` change so that this became an issue?

The Dockerfile installs the packages requirements from a `requirements.txt`. That `requirements.txt` has pinned versions. So a change in a Python package should not be possible (right? ... please don't tell me that this assumption is wrong)

Comment: You can see the history of `python:3.7-slim` at [this link](https://github.com/docker-library/python/commits/7bd9ba302a360d6f66b4abc93ec51813555c33d1/3.7/buster/slim/Dockerfile). Pip was updated to 19.3 three days ago. Doesn't seem likely that would cause your issue.

Comment: Also, to pin the image version further you need to specify the build too, otherwise it will automatically pull the next 3.7.x build release. e.g. `python:3.7.4-slim`

Comment: "Also, to pin the image version further you need to specify the build too" - yes, I'll probably do that. Still, it is super confusing to me why the two c-header requirements suddenly popped up, without having any other new requirement / version